# Android onBackPressed called with previous fragment object

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I'm working on an application that uses multiple fragments that all are extensions of a single one called "Setup"

The classes are as follows:

- Setup extends CustomFragment
- Terms extends Setup
- Privacy extends Setup
- More extends Setup
- Confirm extends Setup
- Enabled extends Setup

This is the flow of app fragments as intended, notice how arrows are bi or single directional to indicate where user can back out of fragment.

The flow of app [image: flow of the app]

I want to lock the user from exiting the Setup activity so he has to make a choice. For that I am using this code:

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
Class classOfCurrentFragment = this.getClass();

if (classOfCurrentFragment == Fragment.class) {
    return true;
} else if (classOfCurrentFragment == TermsFragment.class
        || classOfCurrentFragment == PrivacyFragment.class
        || classOfCurrentFragment == ConfirmFragment.class
        || classOfCurrentFragment == MoreFragment.class) {
    return false;
} else if (classOfCurrentFragment == EnabledFragment.class) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

The result of this function is not quite what I expected.
Back key works in SetupFragment as long as I don't open another one

This is what I read in classOfCurrentFragment.toString()

Correct flow:

> 1. Entering into SetupFragment, press back:
>
> onBackPressed: this.getclass returns class SetupFragment

Now the wrong flow:

> 1. Entering into SetupFragment, then into MoreFragment, press back:
>
> onBackPressed: this.getclass returns class SetupFragment$MoreFragment
>
> this is correct behaviour, we are now in SetupFragment, press back
>   once more:
>
> onBackPressed: this.getclass returns class SetupFragment$MoreFragment
>
> this is incorrect, we are in SetupFragment, yet getclass returns the
>   MoreFragment class.

I suspect this might has to do with generics and some strange Android ways.
Have anyone encountered such strange behaviour before?

Comment: How are you finishing your Fragments?

Comment: Can you make use of addToBackStack()

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez Fragment manager finishes them when I pass the back key I guess

Comment: Ok, I don't know why are you having tis error, but I would try to handle the back button different, with an interface or something better than checking the class, I think this can lead to errors later if you obfuscate your code for example.

Comment: How do you navigate in between fragments? Post that code also.